# How get camera permission from webview android?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, getusermedia

I 0 in java, i just need run my web application in android webview, app use camera.
I have error:

> 2023-05-03 12:41:38.074 4975-4975/com.morservice I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied", source: https://morservicetest.na4u.ru/add-product

But i request permission in Manifest. Right [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java) many code for 6+ android request permission, i use api 30 = android 11. Idk what i need do for fix problem. Can u help me please?

MainActivity

```
package com.morservice;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://morservicetest.na4u.ru/frame");

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.МорСервис"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE:
I try methods from [this topic](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9304) but he not help me:

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(
            new WebChromeClient() {
                 // Grant permissions for cam
                 @Override
                 public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
                     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             Log.d(TAG, request.getOrigin().toString());
                             if (request.getOrigin().toString().equals("file:///")) {
                                 Log.d(TAG, "GRANTED");
                                 request.grant(request.getResources());
                             } else {
                                 Log.d(TAG, "DENIED");
                                 request.deny();
                             }
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
```